# For which values of x does series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

when $\phi$= $\frac{(-1)^{n-3}}{x^{n}(x+n-3)^{0.5}}$

I've tried to tackle this in a few ways, with the ratio test I got =0

I'm not sure where to go from here, once I've proved convergence, how can I work out what values of x we need for this to apply?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's the series?

Answer (score 1):

By series I am assuming you mean the series
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\phi$$
So to do this, we apply the ratio test like you did and get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{x^{n+1}\sqrt{x+n-2}}}{\frac{(-1)^{n-3}}{x^{n}\sqrt{x+n-3}}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x^n\sqrt{x+n-3}}{x^{n+1}\sqrt{x+n-2}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+n-3}}{\sqrt{x+n-2}}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|<1$$
Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\phi_{n+1}/\phi_n|$ is less than one whenever $|1/x|<1$ which means $|x|>1$. Now we just check when $x=1$ and see that the series does converge when $x=1$ via alternating series test.
One can also see right off the bat that the series converges for $|x|\ge 1$ via the alternating series test.